# Java: Drawing single dots at specified (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

I am working on science research and am getting strange results from my code, and as a visual learner I thought it efficient to print my data to screen as it is analysed to try and see where the code is going wrong. For reference, I am analyzing a nonlinear waveform.

Here is the code for analysis:

```
    public void getMachineCode(int trial, int wave){
    double[] tempwave = new double[5000];
    int index = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 5000; x++){
        tempwave[x] = waves[trial][wave][x];
    }
    for(int repeat = 5; repeat > 0; repeat--){
        int tempstart = index;
        if(tempwave[index] > 0){
            while(tempwave[index] > 0){
                index++;
            }
        }else{
            while(tempwave[index] < 0){
                index++;
            }
        }
        int midwave = index - tempstart;
        if(tempwave[midwave] > 0){
            System.out.println(0);
        }else{
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, all I want is to print the (x,y) coordinates of my trial to the screen as the index increases so it is a constantly changing graph, something like:

```
 if(tempwave[index] > 0){
            while(tempwave[index] > 0){
                index++;
                printpixel(index,y);  //something to show where the code is scanning
            }
        }else{
            while(tempwave[index] < 0){
                index++;
                printpixel(index,y);
            }
```

I am not very familiar with java graphics and was looking into using a JFrame but it is hard for me to implement. There will be about 4000 data points to plot, so I might also have to only print every few points or is there a way to make a better visual? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What are the ranges of x and y?

Comment: The ranges can be changed to fit int a screen, but currently x goes from 0 to 4000 and y goes from -0.096851348877 to 0.0940841734409. Not sure if all the extra decimals will create a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you basic idea.

- Normally with Swing graphics, you override the paintComponent() method and draw from some shared state
- Instead you can just draw to a large image, and then draw that image using paintComponent()
- I've compressed this into a single self contained example, this can be separated out in a larger application

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1280, 768,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    };

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   // <== make panel fill frame
    frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // do you drawing somewhere else, maybe a different thread
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x += 5) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y += 5) {
            g.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    g.dispose();
    canvas.repaint();
}
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: Hey thanks, it looks kinda choppy but it works! Any way to possibly smooth out the rectangles or connect them?